# How can I set my desktop to look like this (Ubuntu 18.04) in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, unity, gnome, icons

These images were taken on ubuntu 18.04.

How can I set my desktop to look like this Ubuntu 18.04 in Ubuntu 20.04?

I want to implement these features of Ubuntu 18.04 in ubuntu 20.04.

1. transparent PNG (File or Folder) icons
2. free resizable icons

Is it not possible at all?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason for the unity tag in the question?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you [download and install Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) 20.04.3 LTS or newer.

Kubuntu is an official flavor of Ubuntu, and you can more easily customize it to look like the pictures you attached. Kubuntu had GUI tools to allow you to customize the user interface.

Once you've installed Kubuntu, you will have to move the panel to the the top, and add widgets to your desktop.

You can install the Humanity (or other) icon theme and a desktop theme. These can be easily searched and installed in the System Settings.

You'll quickly learn how to make these changes, and there are a lot of customization options available.